# Iterate over Json object with nested fields

Tags: javascript, json

I am having some difficulties to iterate over a json object. There are some nested fields, and it is getting me confused...

This is my JSON data

```
{
"_embedded": {
    "request_fields": [{
        "reference": null,
        "name": "Qual será o serviço?",
        "label": "Qual será o serviço?",
        "placeholder": "Qual será o serviço?",
        "values": {
            "Coloração": "Coloração",
            "Corte": "Corte",
            "Escova ": "Escova ",
            "Escova progressiva/definitiva": "Escova progressiva/definitiva",
            "Luzes": "Luzes"
        }
    }, {
        "reference": null,
        "name": "Para quem será o serviço?",
        "label": "Para quem será o serviço?",
        "placeholder": "Para quem será o serviço?",
        "values": {
            "Criança": "Criança",
            "Homem": "Homem",
            "Mulher": "Mulher"
        }
    }]
}
}
```

And this is what i`ve tried so far --  **update**

```
  for (key in response) {
                    for (i in response[key].request_fields) {
                        // console.log(response[key].request_fields[i].values);
                        document.getElementById("form").innerHTML +=    "<div class='section'>" + 
                                                                            "<label>" + response[key].request_fields[i].label + "</label>" +
                                                                            "<label>" for (e in response[key].request_fields[i].values) { response[key].request_fields[i].values[e] } "</label>" +
                                                                            "<label>" + response[key].request_fields[i].values{0} + "</label>" +
                                                                        "</div>" ;
                    }
                }
```

Now I am getting

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for

In my 3rd "for" to print "values"

Comment: Do you mean you get "undefined" in the `console.log()` statement, or in your HTML where you use `.values[i]`? I'd expect the latter to be undefined, because `i` isn't one of the property names in the `values` object.

Comment: yes. Im getting it on console.log

Comment: That first `console.log()` works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/46m8kh9t/ - it's only the `values[i]` that I already mentioned which doesn't work.

Comment: I know. My problem actually is this "values" I need to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because the index `i` is not in values, you need either another iterater, or a specific value, or just json it, or join it to a string.

```
for (key in response) {
    for (i in response[key].request_fields) {
        console.log(response[key].request_fields[i].values);
        var values=(()=>{
            var out="";
            for(var ii in response[key].request_fields[i].values){
                out+=ii+": "+response[key].request_fields[i].values[ii]+"\n";
            }
            return out;
        })();
        document.getElementById("form").innerHTML += "<div class='section'>" + "<label>" + response[key].request_fields[i].label + "</label>" + "<label>" + 
        values + "</label>" + "</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: *"or just json it"* - What does that mean?

Comment: hummm. How to "just json it" ?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(response[key].request_fields[i].values)`

Comment: Wouldn't your anonymous function need a `return` statement?

Comment: Honestly, I do not understand what u are doing here, but somehow it worked. 

Could you explain exactly what "var values = ( () => {" do ?

Comment: `(()=>{/*code*/})()` is kinda the same as `(function(){/*code*/})()` except its term is called a arrow function, `An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions